# getting error Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function after installing the fcm plugin

Tags: firebase, push-notification, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have installed the fcm plugin after that I getting below error

```
index.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:171
    at Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/fcm/index.js (index.js:253)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/app.component.ts (app.component.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.module.ts:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12) (anonymous)
```

please let me know if anybody knows the solution